# Magento: How to display customer's phone number on customer information field

Tags: magento

I’m trying to have the customer’s phone number show under the customer account information section. I know the phone number belongs to the customer address section but I’m trying to redesign how the customer account information looks like.

I added a new custom field for Customer ID and I’m able to display it by using the following code as the customer ID belongs to customer_entity.

```
<?php echo $this->__('Identification:') ?><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getCustid()) ?>
```

but now I’m trying to do the same for the telephone number by using this

```
<?php echo $this->__('Telephone:') ?><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getTelephone()) ?>
```

But it doesn’t display any data since it belongs to customer_address_entity and I BELIEVE it should be

```
->getAddress()->getTelephone()
```

instead of

```
->getCustomer()->getTelephone()
```

but using ->getAddress just gives me an error “ Call to a member function getTelephone() on a non-object “

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

As a reference, I'm trying to have this data display on the file customer\account\dashboard\info.phtml

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress()

Comment: Thank you, I tried it to see how that would work but that would not only pull all of the billing address information but it would only display information as long as the customer has a billing address already stored.

In my case, not all customers are required to have a billing address so that wouldn't work for me. Not to mention that I'm only trying to get the customer's phone number out of the address, not every detail of it.

Comment: After you pull getPrimaryBillingAddress try using var_dump to dump the object. In it you should find a field that has the telephone information. If you get a lot of restricted nonsene use getPrimary...()->getData() and one of those will give you the attribute you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Alex Hadley and paperids. (I'm kinda new at Magento). After paperids comment I realized that using $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress() as Alex suggested would work if I added something extra to pull the phone number out of the address and this worked.

    $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone()

It worked like a charm. Now I'm able to pull any information I want from the address and display it anywhere I want to. I completely forgot that the default address upon registration becomes the primary billing and shipping address.

Thanks again =)

Comment: @user1582396 Glad that worked! Posted as an answer below, if you wouldn't mind marking as corrent! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oh, thanks I'll post now! (see comments under original post).

Simply use the following:

```
$this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

The first part will give you all the details, which you could then explore with `var_dump()` as per @paperids.

Comment: If this customer don't have setted primary billing address it return an error (call to a member function in a non object)

Answer (score 5):

This answer should go to @Alex, but just for the sake of completion, I'm posting this as an answer:

Use:

```
$this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone()
```

Comment: Thanks, you caught me sleeping there! I've posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Careful if there is NO address set then this getPrimaryBillingAddress() return a non object.

```
$address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
if ( $address ) echo $address->getTelephone();
```

Answer (score 1):

Luis has mentioned before that if customer didn't setup his billing address you will get an error in return:
**Call to a member function in a non-object.**

If you want to be ready for such situation you can put the code into following IF statement:

```
<?php if ($customerAddressId){ ?>
    <?php $address=Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId); ?>
    <?php $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone(); 
} ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

isLoggedIn()) {

  $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer(); 

  $customerName = $customer->getName(); 
  // like that you can access all other attributes

} 
?>