# Magento Telphone filed in Customer_Account_Edit page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, textfield, savechanges

I want to do the same as this guy do

[Magento: How to display customer's phone number on customer information field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849449/magento-how-to-display-customers-phone-number-on-customer-information-field)

but I don't want only to display the customer phone number, I want to give ability to change the telephone number on this page.

If I follow the guy's above solution I only get the Telephone display in a field but when I submit the form everything else is being saved except this telephone field. What could be the code solution to save the new information after FormSubmission?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE #1**

I update `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/edit.phtml` with this code

`<input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text  <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="telephone" />`

but it doesn't save (form omit changes) if I change the input value and submit the form.
I wonder why..

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: pasted my code. Any suggestions?